# why this code returns undefined when I first run

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I want to get a base64 string from an uploaded image. First time when i run the code, it returns undefined. When i run after it works fine. How can i fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <button id="button" onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var result;

      function getBase64(file) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         reader.onload = function () {
           result = reader.result;
         };
         reader.onerror = function (error) {
           console.log('Error: ', error);
         };
         return result;
      }

      function upload() {
        var file = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
        console.log(getBase64(file));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ASDFGerte [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) does explain this, but I will explain in the context of your question.

Lets examine what happens:

user clicks button

function upload executes

getBase64 is called

create a file reader and read file

assign a function to the `.onload` event listener

assign a function to the `.onerror` event listener

return variable result, which at this point does not exist, because `.onload` event has not been triggered yet.

After your second click, the event has triggered, but for the previous result, not a new result.

The second goal is to fix this, and my favorite way is using the `async await` syntax.

check out this rework of your code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <button id="button" onclick="upload()">Upload</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function getBase64(file) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         let result;
         await new Promise(resolve => {
           reader.onload = function () {
             result = reader.result;
             resolve();
           };
           reader.onerror = function (error) {
             console.log('Error: ', error);
             resolve();
           };
         });
         return result;
      }

      async function upload() {
        var file = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
        const result = await getBase64(file);
        console.log(result);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     return reader.result;
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}

async function upload() {
  var file = document.querySelector('input').files[0];
  let result = await getBase64(file)
  console.log(result);
}
```

`FileReader` runs asynchronously so `reader.onload` does not complete instantly. You return `result` before `reader.onload` has finished so `result` does not have a value.

The second time you run `upload`, result does have a value because `reader.onload` has finished. The result logged will most likely be the result from the previous call to `upload`.

You can fix this by making `upload` an asynchronous function that uteawaits a response from `getBase64`. This will also require you rn the result in `reader.onload` instead of setting the value globally in the `<script>` tag

Comment: thank you for explaining

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `FileReader` outside of `upload()` and use the `onload` function for the `console.log`.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
      
reader.onload = function (event) {
 var dataURL = event.target.result;
 console.log(dataURL);
};
```

in `update` function use only `readDataURL`

```
function upload() {
 var file = document.querySelector("input").files[0];
 reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```